# Golang exit bufio for loop inside another for loop

Tags: go

I have an initial loop that  keep asking user Questions until the user types q to quit.

```
func main() {
 scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
 quit := false
 var city string
 var anything string
 for quit == false {    
     fmt.Println("Enter a city name")
     for scanner.Scan(){
         city= scanner.Text()
         fmt.Printf("q to quit (Anything else to continue): ")
         anything = scanner.Text()
     }
     if anything == "q" {
         fmt.Println(city)
         quit = true
     }
 }
}
```

What I'm struggling to figure out is how I can exit the nested for loop for the scanner and continue on with the initial for loop until the user enters q. Right now, it doesn't exit the 2nd loop so it always prompts "q to quit ..." and when I put a break it exits both the loops.

Any idea how I should tackle this?

Comment: This code doesn't make sense to me. Why is the if statement outside the Scan loop? It never executes until an error occurs.

Comment: It is outside because if the user doesn't enter q, I want the program to ask again to enter a city name

Comment: I think you misunderstand how the Scanner works. Read the docs again. For instance, city and anything will have the same value because the return value of Text() doesn't change until the next call to Scan. There should only be one loop.

Comment: you're right thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want because you don't provide us with sample input and output. Perhaps, based on your code, something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var cities []string
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for {
        fmt.Println("Enter a city name")
        if !scanner.Scan() {
            break
        }
        city := scanner.Text()
        if len(city) > 0 {
            cities = append(cities, city)
        }
        fmt.Printf("q to quit (Anything else to continue): ")
        if !scanner.Scan() || scanner.Text() == "q" {
            break
        }
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", cities)
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a city name
Los Angeles
q to quit (Anything else to continue): 
Enter a city name
London
q to quit (Anything else to continue): 
Enter a city name
Delhi
q to quit (Anything else to continue): q
["Los Angeles" "London" "Delhi"]
```